# Passing Object Type into method as a Parameter?

Tags: java, class, generics, predicate, nhibernate-criteria

I have the following method that returns a `Person` object by Id:

```
   private Person getPersonById(String client) {

    Person output = null;
    EntityManager entityManager = null;

    try {
        entityManager = entityManagement.createEntityManager(client);
        output = entityManager.find(Person.class, id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
     
     // handle
    
    } finally {
        entityManagement.closeEntityManager(client, entityManager);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Is there a way I can make this method more generic so that I can pass in other object types, e.g.
`Place` ,  `Cost` as well? Note that these do not inherit the same super class.

E.g. should I pass e.g. `Person.class` as a method parameter etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to pass in a class object and make your method generic, you could do this:

```
private <E> E getObjectById(String client, Class<E> cls) {

    E output = null;
    EntityManager entityManager = null;

    try {
        entityManager = entityManagement.createEntityManager(client);
        output = entityManager.find(cls, id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
     
     // handle
    
    } finally {
        entityManagement.closeEntityManager(client, entityManager);
    }
    return output;
}
```

If you pass `Person.class` as the `cls` argument, it would be equivalent to your original code.

That's supposing that `entityManager.find` will accept any class and attempt to return an instance of that class.

If `entityManager.find` has some restriction on the characteristics of the class it accepts, you would need to specify them in your generic type parameter `<E>`.